# Cancel/clear item animations

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` list that is set with `DefaultItemAnimator`. With this `ItemAnimator`, adding an item to the bottom will first move the other items up making space to the new item, and then fade in the new item. I need a clean way to cancel, or, more precisely, finish an item animation round prematurely in some cases when two calls to `notifyItemInserted()` are called within a shorter time interval  than the animation duration used by the `ItemAnimator`.